# How to include \noindent to a proof environment

Tags: indentation, amsthm, xpatch

I'm using `amsthm` to get the `proof` environment and `xpatch` to modify it a bit:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% we need to substitute . with a generic command
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{\proofpunctuation}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofpunctuation}{:}
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Beweis}
```

I like to use `\indent` for normal text between the theorems and proofs, but not inside a theorem or a proof. For theorems I defined a new theoremstyle.
But how do I tell the `proof` environment to have `\noindent`?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Do all your proofs contain a single paragraph?

Comment: Absence of a paragraph indent implies continuation of an ongoing idea.  What you are asking for implies that a proof is subsidiary.  (This is not an argument against that point of view, but the reasoning behind the way `proof` is defined in `amsthm`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, but have mercy of your readers and think twice about it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% we need to substitute . with a generic command
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{\proofpunctuation}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\proof}{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofpunctuation}{:}
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Deutsches Ipsum Dolor Currywurst posidonium Frau Professor adhuc Welt sadipscing Schneewittchen at, 
Fußball mei Ich bin ein Berliner gloriatur. Fußball inermis Flughafen accommodare Handtasche Id bitte 
assum Sauerkraut te genau erroribus Vorsprung durch Technik Nec Deutsche Mark amet 
Siebentausendzweihundertvierundfünfzig iriure, HugoClub Mate gloriatur Hackfleisch ut. Knappwurst 
virtute Frau Professor per Oktoberfest At Prost scaevola Ich bin ein Berliner An Die unendliche 
Geschichte malorum HugoClub Mate ius.

Deserunt Grimms Märchen has Grimms Märchen Tollit Deutschland ius Polizei Saepe Döner elaboraret 
Fußball ne, Entschuldigung eu Pfannkuchen pertinax, Reinheitsgebot eripuit Die unendliche Geschichte 
no Kindergarten Diam Die unendliche Geschichte no Meerschweinchen eos Umsatzanalyse suscipit 
Meerschweinchen Eam 99 Luftballons offendit Deutsche Mark ad Lebkuchen voluptatibus 
Bezirksschornsteinfegermeister ad Frau Professor consul Die Toten Hosen vix. Mozart quas Brezel 
veritus Grimms Märchen amet, Aperol Spritz adipiscing Danke sed Schnaps eiusmod Helmut Kohl incididunt 
Landjaeger labore Ampelmännchen dolore Hackfleisch aliqua.

Köln enim Prost minim Nackenheim quis Grimms Märchen exercitation Schneewittchen laboris Autobahn ut 
Fußball ex Milchreis commodo Wurst Duis Nackenheim irure Schmetterling in was machst du in Helmut Kohl 
velit was machst du cillum Danke eu Bezirksschornsteinfegermeister nulla Warmduscher Excepteur Jürgen 
Klinsmann occaecat Köln non Stuttgart sunt Grossbritannien culpa Krankenschwester officia Kirschkerne 
mollit Turnbeutel id Die unendliche Geschichte laborum.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Text courtesy of http://german-ipsum.herokuapp.com

[image]